# Retrieving data with SQL Server from PATSTAT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve patent data with SQL server. My variable of interest is ID, i.e. patent identification. For each ID, I would also like to retrieve several variables for analysis, for instance, the jurisdictions in which a patent have been filed. These can be found by looking at 2 variables: AUTH or L507EP. The values in these columns are not unique for each ID. For instance ID 1 might have 2 rows because AUTH takes 2 values, say US and JP. I would like to avoid having more than 1 row per ID without losing valuable information. So, what I want to do is to identify the different strings in AUTH at the ID level and, create different columns (AUTH1 and AUTH2) that take strings US and JP respectively.

Why I want to do this with SQL instead of Python, R or the like? Because I have restrictions when downloading the data (maximum 700,000 rows) and as I introduce variables that vary over the same ID I substantially increase the number of rows. 
Does any one can help with this? Highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should provide more info. A sample of your input data and what you want to get as output and also the sql code you have tried.

Comment: @TheEsisia Thanks for your interest. This is how my data looks after retrieval: goo.gl/Uj0WBy    As you can see there are several rows for each docb_family_id (patent identifier), because there is variation in terms of psn_id and cited_pat_publn_id. What i would like to get is the following: 1 row per unique docb_family_id with the following columns: appln_filing_year, psn_id1 (with 29708696), psn_id2 (with 9987752), ISR_citations (count 'ISR' citations by docb_family_id iff citn_origin='ISR' and cited_pat_publn_id is not repeated. Is this possible? – luiscanyamel 5 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

To get unique ids and having the psn numbers in the same row you can use this:

```
 select id, psn, psn2 
 from
     (select row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as num, id, psn, lead(psn) over(order by id) as psn2 from MyTable) as T
 where num %2 == 0
 Group By id, psn, psn2
```

I did not understand what you said about SEA.